# Create event method for control shortcut - Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

Is there a shortcut to add an event method for a control? If I have a button, I want to add the Click method without having to type it out or switch to design view.

EDIT: 

Seriously! When i did this in VB I had a drop down list of all the controls and their events. Is that so hard to do for C#?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Winforms? Webforms? What?

One option is to (after initialization) hook the event your self - intellisense supplies the event name, and [Tab][Tab] creates the method stub - i.e.

```
public MyForm()
{
    InitializeComponent()
    someButton.Click += (press [tab][tab] now)
}
```

and it does the rest... likewise in web-forms at the appropriate place.

This gives you:

```
public MyForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    someButton.Click += new EventHandler(someButton_Click);
}

void someButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException(); // your code here ;-p
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked into creating a snippet?  Here is a snippet I use to create anonymous methods that hook up to an event.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<CodeSnippets  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
    <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
        <Header>
            <Title>anonymous</Title>
            <Shortcut>__anonymous</Shortcut>
            <Description>Code snippet for an anonymous method</Description>
            <Author>Andrew</Author>
            <SnippetTypes>
                <SnippetType>Expansion</SnippetType>
            </SnippetTypes>
        </Header>
        <Snippet>
            <Declarations>
                <Literal>
                    <ID>event</ID>
                    <Default>base.Init</Default>
                    <ToolTip>Event to attach</ToolTip>
                </Literal>
                <Literal>
                    <ID>args</ID>
                    <Default>EventArgs</Default>
                    <ToolTip>Event argument type</ToolTip>
                </Literal>
                <Literal>
                    <ID>name</ID>
                    <Default>args</Default>
                    <ToolTip>Event arg instance name</ToolTip>
                </Literal>
            </Declarations>
            <Code Language="csharp"><![CDATA[$event$ += delegate(Object sender, $args$ $name$) {
                $end$
            };]]>
            </Code>
        </Snippet>
    </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```

Also [here is an article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165392(VS.80).aspx) explaining how to create them and how they work.

Comment: it looks like a great thing, i ll try it as soon as possible.
Thanks for the info

Answer (score 1):

```
public partial class MyUserControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{

public delegate void ButtonClickEventHandler(object sender,EventArgs e);
public Event ButtonClickEventHandler Button_Click;

 protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Button_Click!= null)
                Button_Click(sender,e);
        }
}
```

Default.aspx

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnInit(e);
            MyUserControl.Button_Click+= MyUserControl_Button_Click;
        }

 void MyUserControl_Button_Click(object sender,EventArgs e)
        { }
```